# Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\ImageManager::upload()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload an image into my database. When i do upload, i get this error below

> > Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\ImageManager::upload()

Searching on the internet for solutions, i found this method

adding this line `'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' in my $providers in config/app.php`

adding this line `'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' in my $aliases in config/app.php`

In my controller as well, i have use Image.  But then i am still getting this error above. What could i be missing please?

**Controller**

```
public function uploadImagePost(UploadUserImageRequest $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        $image = $request->file('profile_image');

        if (false === empty($user->image_path)) {
            $user->image_path->destroy();
        }

        $relativePath = 'uploads/users/' . $user->id;
        $path = $relativePath;


        $dbPath = $relativePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $this->directory(public_path($relativePath));

        Img::upload($image, $path);

        $user->update(['image_path' => $dbPath]);

        return redirect()->route('my-account.home')
            ->with('notificationText', 'User Profile Image Uploaded successfully!!');
    }
```

Comment: Did you import the Image class in your controller?. Please add your controller code here.

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy, beneath my question, i said `in my controller, i import the class like use Image`  .. Controller updated

Comment: Try to run composer dump-autoload .

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy controller has been updated

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads There is no upload method. You should be using save method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library you have used doesn't have upload() method. Use save() method for saving the file.

```
// read image from temporary file
$img = Image::make($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

// save image
$img->save('foo/bar.jpg');
```

Refer [this link for more details](http://image.intervention.io/)